# error when move files to pvc inside dockerfile

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I use a mounted kubernetes pvc and i need to move binary conf directory inside this pvc
so i try in my dockerfile to move files using the mv command like follow but when i have the error /apps/files/conf not such file or directory in the logs of my pod (pod created using the build image). I have the same error when i try to move a file testy.txt to PVC files

```
RUN mv /apps/conf /apps/files/conf  
RUN ln -s apps/files/conf   /apps/conf
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please share the yaml manifest of your pods and pvc as well

Comment: The image build doesn't run with any mounted volumes.  It most likely isn't even running inside the cluster where the Kubernetes volumes will eventually exist.  You can't do this step in a Dockerfile at all.